# Why awk does not show the correct record length?

Tags: awk, aix

I'm concerned regarding what `awk` shows as the record length.  I'm checking some files for a specific record length - awk shows the result I wanted, but the file size shows that each record in the file is actually larger than what `awk` says by 1 byte.

```
$ ls -l some_file.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 foo   bar           250614 Oct 20 08:49 some_file.txt

$ awk '{ print length }' some_file.txt | sort -u
458

$ echo "(250614%458)" | bc
88

$ echo "(250614%459)" | bc
0
```

Notice that the `bc` result is wrong with a record length of `458`, but seems fine with a record length of `459`.  Also, `awk` + `sort` shows that **all** records have a record length of `458`.  My educated guess is that `awk` is not accounting for the *End Of Line* character, hence making a real record length of `459`.  What do you think?

ps: `awk` on `AIX 5.3`

Comment: In `awk`, is the output record separator `ORS` not set to the newline character therefore it is classed as a seperator instead of a character?

Comment: How can I check what is currently set for `ORS` in my `awk`?

Comment: Sorry - I meant the defaul Record seperator (`RS`) **NOT** `ORS`.

Comment: You can actually print the RS from within awk, it will print a newline (`echo | awk '{print RS}'`).

Comment: Yes, it does print a `newline` - I guess that means that the `RS` is set to `newline`...  therefore, that is what accounts for the extra byte then?

Comment: Yep , a way to test this would be to change the value of `RS` to something that does not exist in the file so it ignores the newline character and counts all the characters. **e.g.** `awk 'BEGIN {RS=":"} {print length}'` some_file.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default Record Separator `RS` is set to newline.

Therefore `awk` will interpret this as a separator instead of a character in the length.

To check what `RS` is set to:

```
echo | awk '{print "\""RS"\""}'
"
"
```

The quotes are seperated by a newline showing the `RS` value.

To confirm that the `RS` character is not included in the length output:

```
$ echo test > some_file.txt
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user    5 Oct 20 16:33 some_file.txt
```

Show the length with `RS` set to newline.

```
$ awk '{print length}' some_file.txt
4
```

Set `RS` to be a character that does not exist in the file and count again:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS=":"} {print length}' some_file.txt
5
```

The additional character is now included.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is perfectly normal. By default, awk does not include the newline character in a record.

From the [POSIX standard for awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/awk.html):

> Input shall be interpreted as a sequence of records. By default, a record is a line, less its terminating <newline>
>   ...
>   String Functions
>      length[([s])] - Return the length, in characters, of its argument taken as a string, or of the whole record, $0, if there is no argument.